# How to Interleave the items of a vector to replace NAs with preceding values in R

Tags: r

I have this vector `myvec`. I want to remove all the NAs and replace them with the preceding items and get the result.

myvec

```
c("AMLM12001KP", NA, "1114002", NA, "1121501", NA, "1231401", 
NA, NA, NA)
```

result

```
AMLM12001KP  AMLM12001KP  1114002  1114002  1121501  1121501  1231401 
1231401  1231401  1231401
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `na.locf`

```
library(zoo)
na.locf(myvec)
#[1] "AMLM12001KP" "AMLM12001KP" "1114002"     "1114002"     "1121501"    
#[6] "1121501"     "1231401"     "1231401"     "1231401"     "1231401"
```